# Ender3 v2 on Marlin moves head while rotating button

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin, firmware

I updated firmware on my Ender3 v2. Previously I used to have precompiled 2.0.7. Now I compiled 2.0.9 from source. Everything seems to work fine except of Move menu. Previously, I pushed the button to select axis in menu, rotated the button to set move value, and pushed again to confirm and only after confirm my head started to move. Using new firmware, I push the button to select axis, rotate the button - and head starts moving during rotation, not waiting until I push button to confirm move.

Could anyone help me out, which config parameter is responsible for this behavior? Or was it changed inside firmware?

Comment: Did you alsoupdate the firmware of the display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the firmware you may have the option to disable live motion. Marlin has different UI for the Ender3V2 (DWIN type display), which you can choose in the configuration.h file just after the line:

```
// Ender-3 v2 OEM display. A DWIN display with Rotary Encoder.
```

You can enable the **DWIN_LCD_PROUI** to get the option to desactive live motion

```
//#define DWIN_CREALITY_LCD           // Creality UI
#define DWIN_LCD_PROUI              // Pro UI by MRiscoC
```

You can also look for other Marlin forks with more implemented features, for example:

[image: Move axis menu]

Comment: Thank you. Had no idea it depends on UI. Although DWIN_LCD_PROUI still have live motion enabled (i use 2.0.x Marlin branch), I tried another options and found what i need. So it's not a promotion ;) Thanks a lot.